# How can I export public key in PEM format with GnuPG?

Tags: gnupg, openssl, public-key

I'm writing SW that uses opessl library for verifying DSA signatures. I have public keys from senders in gpg format. How can I convert those into .pem so that openssl can read them?

I found this from another thread:

```
gpgsm -o secret-key.p12 --export-secret-key-p12 0xXXXXXXXX
```

To do the export I need to have the keys in gpgsm keyring don't I? I just can't figure out how to import my keys into the keyring gpgsm is using. I end up with errors:

```
gpgsm --import public.asc
gpgsm: total number processed: 0
gpgsm: error importing certificate: End of file
```

Can `gpgsm` somehow use gpg:s keyring and do the export from there?

Answer (score 0):

Your export command is correct but as you suppose, the `gpgsm`'s keyring is empty. You can check that with:

```
gpgsm --list-keys
```

The output will be nothing.

For your last question: Nope. `gpg` and `gpgsm` use different databases. More info is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/836895/do-gpg-and-gpgsm-use-the-same-key-database). You have to create or obtain an OpenSSL key/cert pair and import it (in PKCS#12 format) into gpgsm keyring (usually `~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx`) so the import command must be:

```
gpgsm --import mycert.p12
```

---

You can export the keys from one system, convert them and import to another one, but the so-called conversion just supplies the metainfo (in most cases) and a brand new cert/key is being created with that metainfo. You can look [here](http://www.sysmic.org/dotclear/index.php?post/2010/03/24/Convert-keys-betweens-GnuPG%2C-OpenSsh-and-OpenSSL) for conversion examples.